# React Native border radius makes outline

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, outline

I would like to make the circle view by using react-native.

Here what I did:

```
circle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    borderWidth: 10,
    borderColor: '#fff',
    top: 20,
    left: 30,
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 150 / 2,
    backgroundColor: '#ED1D27',
  }
```

And view

```
<View style={styles.circle}></View>
```

The result is:

[image]

There is and outline rounded the circle.

I don't want that outline. I checked by remove the border radius and it has no outline like below:

[image]

I have no idea for this issue, please help me...

Comment: Maybe someone will find a workaround but in my opinion this looks like a bug in the Stylesheet implementation as this behaviour is clearly not intended. If it's not on the bug tracker already, it should be put there.

Comment: What version of React Native are you on? Tried your code on RN42 and there's no outline.

Comment: Yes, I will search and put there. I also think that is a bug.

Comment: You meant RN 0.42? I am using the latest version of react-native.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is a [runnable example on repl.it](https://repl.it/Hws9/0); I get no ugly border outline on my phone using "Expo client" app to view the result (Android 7).

Comment: @HuguesMoreau it happened in iOS.

Comment: Yes, my own test is not worth much, but the link lowers the barrier for an iOS user to test your issue :)

Answer (score 11):

So I am not entirely sure why it gives that very small red border with your current rule. It could be an actual bug. Regardless if I understand correctly, you want a circle without that small red border. You can achieve that by removing your border property:

```
position: 'absolute',
top: 20,
left: 30,
width: 150,
height: 150,
borderRadius: 150 / 2,
backgroundColor: '#ED1D27',
```

Resulting in:

[image]

If you do want a border, a potential workaround could be:

```
inner: {
  position: 'relative',
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  borderRadius: 150 / 2,
  backgroundColor: '#ED1D27',
},
outter:{
  position: 'absolute',
  paddingTop:10,
  paddingLeft:10,
  top: 20,
  left: 30,
  width: 170,
  height: 170,
  borderRadius: 160 / 2,
  backgroundColor: '#000',
},
```

With a view heirarchy like:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.outter}>
      <View style={styles.inner}></View>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Maybe, it's a bug. Anyway, I am working on the solution same as you mentioned. But I don't really like this one. Maybe, I have to report this bug on the react-native repo. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Luc You're welcome, glad I could help. If you think this is the answer feel free to accept it. I really don't like it either. I'm actually investigating as to why it does this. Apparently it only happens on iOS too so I may be a tricky one to squash.


Follow up: Apparently someone else has [run into this too](http://techqa.info/programming/question/41663739/react-native---ios---circle-with-border---circle-background-color-spilling-out-of-circle). I suppose this is the workaround for now.

Answer (score 3):

RE-EDIT: Turns out that this [border-radius issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=431176) is [not isolated](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426217) to working with react alone, but a general css known issue, that has been raised [and marked as fixed] numerous times. I found this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/border-radius-and-inset-box-shadow-bug-solution/), that cites they found a solution, but also states the cause. The link in question's problem cites it initially as being related to box-shadow but from a quick google search there seems to many issues with border-radius.

**Given cause:**

> It turns out that if your border radius is larger than the height of
>   the element (taking in to account padding, font-size, and so forth)
>   this visual error will occur.

A fiddle is given in the [github](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/318) link http://jsfiddle.net/2HqTZ/ (with html2canvas)

---

Earlier proposed solution  [answer 1- link to expo](https://repl.it/HxEh)

Edited earlier proposed solution [answer 2 - expo link](https://repl.it/HxEh/1)

**Current/ best solution  (of mine) IMHO** [link](https://repl.it/HxEh/4)

I think this is the best solution. I noted that if the border color was left out in the circedge css but left in only the circle css, the border 'outline' effect is greatly reduced. I also replaced borderRadius with borderTopLeftRadius etc after reading the known issues on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.square} />
        <View style={styles.circedge}/>
        <View style={styles.circle}>
         </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 2,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  square: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 30,
    left: 30,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  circle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    borderColor: '#fff',
    top: 60,
    left: 60,
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderTopLeftRadius:150/2,
    borderTopRightRadius:150/2,
    borderBottomLeftRadius:150/2,
    borderBottomRightRadius:150/2,
    backgroundColor: '#ED1D27',
  },
  circedge:{
     position: 'absolute',
     paddingTop:10,
     paddingLeft:10,
     top: 50,
     left: 50,
     width: 170,
     height: 170,
     borderTopLeftRadius:170/2,
     borderTopRightRadius:170/2,
     borderBottomLeftRadius:170/2,
    borderBottomRightRadius:170/2,
     backgroundColor: '#fff',
  }
});
```

Comment: https://repl.it/HxEh/4  I note that if i omit the border color on the edge css but leave it in only the circle css, the border 'line' effect is greatly reduced. Also replaced borderRadius with borderTopLeftRadius etc after reading the notes on caniuse

Comment: Setting the borderColor to white was the solution for our issue: Strange artifacts appearing on e.g. react native Image assets with rounded corners